# Compare dates in Java

Tags: java, date

I have a problem with comparison of two dates. I tried to compare it with Date `.after()` method, put it to Calendar object and then compare, but still it doesn't work properly.
Ex. when I put `startDate` as 2017-01-26 and `endDate` as 2017-01-28 then it shows, that `startDate` is after! But when I put `startDate` as date before 2017-01-23 (ex. 2017-01-01) and `endDate` as 2017-01-28 then everything is ok...

I have View with two spinners like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat model = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
spinnerStartDate = new JSpinner(new SpinnerDateModel());
spinnerStartDate.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinnerStartDate, model.toPattern()));
spinnerStartDate.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(new Date(1485039600000L), null, null, Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
panel.add(spinnerStartDate);

SimpleDateFormat model2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
spinnerEndDate = new JSpinner(new SpinnerDateModel());
spinnerEndDate.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinnerEndDate, model2.toPattern()));
spinnerEndDate.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(new Date(1485039600000L), null, null, Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
panel.add(spinnerEndDate);
```

And two methods to get Date:

```
 public Date getStartDate(){
          return (Date)spinnerStartDate.getValue();
   }
  public Date getEndDate(){
       return (Date)spinnerEndDate.getValue();
   }
```

and Listener

```
public void addFilterListener(ActionListener act){
    btnFilter.addActionListener(act);
}
```

Then I have Controller where I have to check, if second date isn't after than first.

```
    class FilterListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Date date1 = View.getStartDate();
            Date date2 = View.getEndDate();

                if(date1.after(date2)){
                    System.out.println("date1 is after! change it!");
                    System.out.println("Date 1 " + date1);
                    System.out.println("Date 2 " + date2);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("No");
                }
     }
 }
```

I have no idea what is wrong. In other part of code this comparison work properly on the same basis!

Comment: Could you add `System.out.println("Date 1 " + date1);` and `System.out.println("Date 2 " + date2);` into your comparison method and see what dates are you getting in it?

Comment: Output for startDate 2016-01-26 and endDate 2016-01-29 `date1 is after! change it!
Date 1 Thu Jan 26 00:00:00 CET 2017
Date 2 Sun Jan 22 00:00:00 CET 2017` 
I have no idea, why the second date is Jan 22?!

Comment: Could you post the code that calls this method? It seems incorrect dates are passed.

Comment: Added more code to the post. That's all. I know that incorrect dates are passed (enddate), but this is all the code in this method.

Comment: Is `View` an object of a class? Or `startDate` and `endDate` are static members? Need to check which methods sets these two, maybe the previous value does not get removed and it still returns previous value?

Comment: Yes, view is an object of a class, spinners aren't static members.
I figured out, that if I don't change value of the spinner, then it pass always 2017-01-22, but spinner shows today date. Do you now how to change it? Maybe just set it in the constructor?

Comment: I see `22-01-2017` too, but if you want today's date, you should instantiate `Date` without any arguments.

Comment: Yes, can you try changing `spinnerStartDate.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(new Date(1485039600000L), null, null, Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));` to `spinnerStartDate.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(new Date(), null, null, Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));`?

Comment: Very stupid mistake! Thanks for help guys, @DarshanMehta it works perfectly. Put it into answer, please, so I mark it as correct

Comment: @naveen.singh done..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are getting `2017-01-22` as date is because of these two lines:

```
spinnerStartDate.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(new Date(1485039600000L), null, null, Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));

spinnerEndDate.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(new Date(1485039600000L), null, null, Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
```

That's because `1485039600000L` is `22-Jan-2017` in milliseconds, below code shows this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Date date = new Date(1485039600000L);
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

Now, if you want it to show current date then you need to use `no argument constructor` of `Date` class, i.e. your `setModel` statements will change to the following:

```
spinnerStartDate.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(new Date(), null, null, Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));

spinnerEndDate.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(new Date(), null, null, Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
```

Comment: Thank you once again for help